# maximum weight k-edge problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

Given positive integer $k$ and an undirected graph $(V,E)$, with nonnegative (non-uniform) weights on the nodes. Find $k$ edges whose spanning nodes have the maximum weight.

Is this in P or NP? I tend to believe this has been studied before but could not find a reference.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no, it's not. A question from a friend.